# Store a workbook in a Xlam

Tags: excel, vba, add-in

There is a workbook which I need to add to a Xlam file (add-in). The idea is simple, a macro is run and then the new workbook is shown/open. 
One may suggest the following code:

```
Workbooks.Open "\\someNetworkDrive\myworkbook.xlsx"
```

Different users store the workbook in different paths. So the above solution doesn't work. (Moreover, The user may not have the workbook) Does any one know a way to attach the xlsx file to the xlam file?

Another approach would be to store this workbook in a VBA variable of the type workbook and then show/open it when the macro is run. But I don't know how to store an already created workbook to a VBA code.

Any idea?

Comment: You can't store a workbook inside a workbook - your best bet is to ask the user to select the workbook using a file dialog

Comment: Ok, what about creating sheets inside the xlam and showing them when the macro is run, is it possible?

Comment: An add-in is hidden by default, but you could copy/create a worksheet from the add-in to the active workbook which would make it show. No good if you want to store the data back to the add-in - but that's not really the point of an add-in anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to have a single workbook solution then you need to embed the worksheets in the xlam, then create a new workbook and copy the worksheets etc into it. You may be able just to store the formats and formulas etc in your XLAM and then your VBA code in the XLAM uses them to create the new workbook.
This approach works well when you have a variable number of rows etc to create.

Answer (score 1):

Save over-complicating the code and just ask the user to locate the workbook instead:

```
Sub SO()

Dim fileLocation   As String
Dim myWB           As Excel.Workbook

fileLocation = Application.GetOpenFileName("Excel Workbook (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")

If Not UCase(fileLocaation) = "FALSE" And Not fileLocation = vbNullString Then
    Set myWB = Workbooks.Open(fileLocation)
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I understand it works, but I am looking for a single file solution. I could merge the code of my existing file with the xlam file, but still I would have to create a new worksheet to run the merged code. Is there a way to add sheets to a Xlam file?

Comment: An add-in isn't designed to be used as a workbook, it's purpose is to extend the properties and features of Excel and so in my personal opinion, I think you're approaching the problem the wrong way. Why don't you post the code that you're trying to get working as there is probably another way of using it without creating a worksheet.

Comment: The code is too long. There are 5 modules. But basically it fills some worksheet with the requested data by the user also generate some graphs. So it is necessary to create a new workbook so the user can manipulate the requested data and save it to his computer.

Comment: Then I don't understand why the solution provided above wouldn't work? You can use the existing add-in and just reference the opened workbook with an object variable.

Comment: The users are not prepared. They may change the file location and the idea is to integrate all services into a single xlam file. After all, that was my boss request. As a business grad and I don't really know the best approach when it comes to programming but I may ask him about it. Thanks

Comment: I am going to use this code to create a new wbook. 
Workbooks.Add
And then I will make a VBA to populate this workbook exactly as the other one. Is it possible?

Comment: If they can open a workbook then they are prepared, try the code first and see for yourself.